# Can I use innerHTML to change the html of one item more than once?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, html5-audio, innerhtml

Im making a game with different rounds, in round 1 I want the 3 list items to appear as media players, and then in round 2 I want those media players to change back to just text.

Ive tried the innerHTML code for both media player and text and they both work seperately, but when when they are one after the other the media players stay and the text doesnt appear.

Comment: yes? of course you can

Comment: Show some code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The DOM isn't rendered until the JavaScript completes. So if you do both changes in one function call, you won't see the intermediate state.